# Как корректно создать исключение?

Tags: c#

Имеется следующий метод:

```
    public async Task<int> PaymentOrderAsync(int orderId, int userId)
    {
        await using(var db = new TelegramShopDBContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == userId) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("⚠️ Пользователь не найден");
                var order = await db.Orders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == orderId) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("⚠️ Заказ не был найден");
                var product = await db.Products.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.NameProduct == order.NameProduct && p.Value >= order.Value) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("‍♀️ Извините, но товар закончился");
                if (user.Balance >= order.TotalPrice)
                {
                    user.Balance -= order.TotalPrice;
                    order.Status = "Ожидает выполнения";
                    product.Value -= order.Value;
                    return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    return 
                }
            }
            catch(DbException)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

У меня возник вопрос. Насколько корректно будет создавать исключение если у Юзера будет недостаточно средств на балансе и каким оно должно быть?(Я имею ввиду блок else)

Comment: если ты будешь писать логику в этом методе, то исключение вызывать не имеет смысла

Comment: @Lofectr, тут как раз логика и заканчивается, что мне что-то нужно вернуть из метода) Я вот и подумал создавать исключение

Comment: `order.Status = "Недостаточно средств"; return 0;` зачем вам исключения здесь?

Comment: @aepot, если человек нажимает "Оплатить заказ", то я же его как-то должен проинформировать)

Comment: Гм, по-моему, все эти запросы следует как минимум обернуть в транзакцию. Потому что в нагруженной системе цены и количество товаров могут измениться в промежутке между отдельными запросами.

Comment: По поводу исключения. Хотите - бросайте. Можете взять одно из стандартных (пожалуй, подойдёт InvalidOperationException), можете создать своё (что-то вроде InsufficientAmountException)

Comment: Исключения надо создавать тогда, когда нет возможности вернуть результат или продолжить выполнение кода. Логика работы приложения никак не должна быть связана с исключениями. Исключения - для исключительных ситуаций. А нехватка денег - ситуация не исключительная.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, а каким образом это сделать?) Я просто никогда такого не делал. Не могли бы вы набросать небольшой примерчик или кинуть ссылочку на ресурсы или примеры?

Comment: `catch(DbException) { return 0;` - возвращается 0 в случае исключения в работе с БД. `return await db.SaveChangesAsync();` - возаращается количество затронутых строк. Если уж вы в двух разных ситуациях возвращаете коды, то и в третьей ситуации, вероятно, следует поступить аналогично.

Comment: Кстати, ваш `try-catch` не ловит ошибки создания самого контекста. То есть `new TelegramShopDBContext()` может выкинуть исключение.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Исключения надо создавать в исключительных ситуациях, например есть такой метод

```cs
int Divide(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

Почему оператор деления создает исключение приделении на ноль? Потому что он не может поместить результат такого деления в переменную типа `int`. То есть возврат из метода невозможен при делении на ноль, вот тогда и выбрасывается исключение.

А что делать, если мы знаем, что ноль в делителе - нормальное дело, и мы хотим например логически обработать эту исключительную ситуацию, а точнее - не допустить ее возникновения, что вы собственно и делаете в вашем коде - проверяете, хватает ли денег на балансе.

```cs
bool TryDivide(int a, int b, out int result)
{
    bool success = b != 0,
    result = success ? a / b : 0;
    return success;
}
```

Когда логика приложения предупреждает возникновение исключения, выброс его не требуется.

*Обратите внимание: защитная логика, это не когда вы поймали исключение внутри метода, а когда вы предупредили его, то есть не допустили его появления. Обёртываение в `try-catch` не является защитной логикой, а является обработкой уже возникшего исключения.*

```cs
// ПЛОХОЙ КОД, НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК
bool TryDivide(int a, int b, out int result)
{
    try
    {
        result = a / b;
        return true;
    {
    catch (DivisionByZeroException)
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Вот если бы ваша база данных следила за целостностью данных, то есть запрещала бы отрицательный баланс при списаниях, а вы бы невзирая на баланс пытались бы выполнить транзакцию, вот тогда бы исключение имело бы место быть.

Есть защитная логика - нет исключения. Нет защитной логики - есть исключение. Но решать в конечном итоге, как оно будет работать только вам.

Comment: Можно я немного не соглашусь? С точки зрения производительности - блок try дешевле блока if в программах с большими таблицами переходов. Хоть пример, с try-catch плохой, но в некоторых ситуациях он может быть лучше.

Comment: @Blackmeser `блок try дешевле блока if` заинтриговали. Let-it-crash?

Comment: к сожалению, когда crash - тогда уже не дешевле =( PS отработка блока try без ошибок не сбрасывает конвеер, в отличии от неправильно предсказанного ветвления if, это как минимум. С таблицами - куда интереснее, как-то натыкался на статью с падением производительности при забивании таблицы переходов.

Answer (score 4):

Чем больше я смотрел на этот код, тем больше у меня возникало к нему вопросов. Часть из них я высказал в комментариях, но чувствую, что нужно их собрать воедино и описать подробно.

В одних случаях вы бросаете исключения для сигнализации о некоторых ошибках:

```
throw new ArgumentNullException("⚠️ Пользователь не найден");
throw new ArgumentNullException("⚠️ Заказ не был найден");
throw new ArgumentNullException("‍♀️ Извините, но товар закончился");
```

При этом сообщения сразу локализованы на русский (как вы будете переводить приложение на другой язык?) и содержат смайлики (тут нецензурные выражения) - то есть они явно предназначены для вывода конечному пользователю.

В другом случае вы возвращаете код ошибки:

```
catch(DbException)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Также, в случае успеха возвращаете количество затронутых строк:

```
return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Выше по коду вы, вероятно, проверяете возвращённое значение и в зависимости от него предпринимаете те или иные действия. Подозреваю, что не проверяете...

Даже если не учитывать, что `SaveChanges()` тоже может вернуть `0`, получается сложная система обработки результата.

Кстати, ваш `try-catch` не ловит ошибки создания самого контекста. То есть `new TelegramShopDBContext()` может выкинуть исключение. Но это не самая большая проблема, т. к. легко решается.

---

Резюмируя, как бы можно было решить всё это дело? Не знаю. Потому что неизвестно, как и что у вас сделано выше по коду. Есть ли централизованная обработка ошибок (middleware exception handling), используются ли кастомные исключения и многие прочие факторы.