# не могу понять в чем моя ошибка sqlite c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

пытаюсь найти столбец с определенным значением, но у меня нет такого значения в базе, но результат я получаю что `"Такой существует"`. Собвственно вопрос в чем у меня ошибка?

```
        try
        {
            OpenConnection();
            _sqliteCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RegisteredPlayers WHERE nickname = 'niik'";
            _sqliteCommand.ExecuteReader();
            CloseConnection();
            Debug.Log("Такой существует");
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
            return true;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда не обрабатывайте так исключения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277782/373567

Comment: Так вы проверьте, что вернул метод `ExecuteReader`. Потому что `Debug.Log` в любом случае отработает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я давно пользовался, но уверен что код работает как нужно и здесь логическая ошибка.

Мне кажется, что дело в том, что ты почему-то решил что он должен пофейлится. А он не должен. Он должен вернуть тебе пустую таблицу. То есть кетч не сработает.

Ты должен проверять результат работы запроса и на основе него делать вывод о том есть ли такой плеер в таблице или нет.

То есть если количество строк в таблице результатов равно нулю == такого пользователя нет. Если больше нуля == то в таблице есть такие плееры.