# Как можно реализовать механизм исключений в данной функции?

Tags: c#

```
            public static Power Make_Stepen(double first, int second)
        {
            string error = "Функции не понравились ваши введенные данные!";
            Power pw1 = new Power(first, second);
                if (!pw1.Init(first, second))
                {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
                }
                return pw1;
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Потратьте чуть больше усилий, чем один Ctrl+V, чтобы задать вопрос. Ничего не понятно. Отформатируйте пожалуйста код.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277782/373567

Comment: `if (!pw1.Init(first, second)) { throw new SomeException(error); }`