# Как заменить try catch на нормальную запись

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        /*Col6. * Даны два массива из целых чисел от 1 до 100: длины n и длины N (n < N). 
         * Определить для каждого подмассива (непрерывный отрезок массива) 
         * второго массива длины n, является ли он перестановкой первого массива.*/
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Test(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, new int[] { 9, 2, 3, 4 })); //true
            Console.WriteLine(Test(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, new int[] { 4, 2, 5 })); //false
        }
        static bool Test(int[] bigArray, int[] smallArray)
        {
            foreach (var i in smallArray)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (bigArray[Array.IndexOf(bigArray, i) + 1] == smallArray[Array.IndexOf(smallArray, i) + 1])
                        return true;
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "нормальная запись" - это какая?

Comment: без true и catch

Comment: просто проверяй что вернул Array.IndexOf и значение внутри границ массива

Comment: Как сделать так чтобы не проверяло последний элемент массива?

Comment: ты знаешь индекс который получил, ты знаешь индекс который надо пропустить. достаточно сравнить их и пропустит, если нужно

Comment: откуда вообще в формуле взялся `+ 1`?

Comment: ну подмассив же считается если если хотя бы два элемента из маленького массива есть в большом. И я просто нахожу элемент из маленького в большом и если следующий элемент в маленьком совпадает со следующим элементом в большом, то true.

Comment: ты упускаешь момент, что в большом массиве не обязательно будет элемент из маленького, как собственно и то, что для последнего элемента нет следующего.

Comment: Все из-за неверного выбора способа обхода массива - `foreach` - всегда проходит все элементы, если тебе нужно что-то другое, нужно либо использовать другой тип цикла, например `for`, либо предварительно обработать массив

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277782/373567 в тему