# Как лучше оформить метод с предусловиями?

Tags: c#, методы, условия, чистый-код, оформление

Есть два метода. Первый вариант:

```
public void MethodOne(uint value)
{
    if (value < 100)
    {
        if (value % 2 != 0)
        {
            // код метода
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ExceptionTwo();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ExceptionOne();
    }
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
public void MethodTwo(uint value)
{
    if (value >= 100)
        throw new ExceptionOne();
        
    if (value % 2 == 0)
        throw new ExceptionTwo();

    // код метода
}
```

Какой из них наиболее предпочтителен?

Comment: а не проще вместе условия выполнения метода соединить с помощью логического И?

Comment: @xmikex, предполагается, что исключения могут повлиять на логику выполнения программы вне этого метода (на выброшенное исключение ExceptionOne - одно действие, на ExceptionTwo - другое действие).

Comment: Второй вариант явно выглядит чище. (зы: а все эти фигурные скобки у C# на новой строке только угрезняют код имхо)

Comment: Лучше всего было бы использовать [контракты](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts). Но проект умер. Не менее здорово было бы использование [Dafny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dafny). Но проект до сих пор в стадии исследований.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277782/373567

Comment: ИМХО, второй вариант хороший, но нужно ещё предусмотреть стек вызовов, чтобы он попал куда надо.

Answer (score 3):

> Предполагается, что исключения могут повлиять на логику выполнения программы вне этого метода (на выброшенное исключение ExceptionOne - одно действие, на ExceptionTwo - другое действие)

Есть шанс, что в вашем случае вообще не должно быть исключений. Исключение - это не ошибка. Это реально неожиданная, исключительная ситуация.

- Двери лифта открылись - а лифта нет - это исключение.
- Вы нажали 16 этаж, а лифт по дороге остановился на 10-ом - не исключение.

Exception не стоит использовать в пути выполнения, который является обычным (не исключительным) с точки зрения кода.

Если у вас есть некий вызывающий код, который реально ожидает, что этот метод бросит исключение, и в котором есть нормальный, частый путь выполнения, который завязан на тип исключения - значит вам стоит переписать код без исключений, на возврат какого-нибудь Result вместо void.

Comment: Действительно, вы правы. В данном примере я бы мог использовать вместо выбрасывания исключения возврат определённого значения. Возможно, это даже было бы более оптимальным с точки зрения производительности. Тем не менее, в этом вопросе я хотел уделить внимание не столько тому, что должно произойти при невыполнении предусловий, сколько расположению этих условий в коде метода.

Comment: @Egorqs для основного пути выполнения (без исключений) количество проверок одинаковое, для неосновных - бросание исключения дороже по скорости, чем порядок проверок. писать if-ки вложенно или друг под другом - вообще без разницы, это вкусовщина, никакой "оптимальности" в вариантах быть не может, пишите как хотите. 2-й вариант удобнее в мерже при работе нескольких человек надо кодом, и условно более читаем (меньше вложенность), я бы взял его. Если вам нравится первый - берите первый

Comment: @Egorqs можете еще вот этим померять: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-metrics-values?view=vs-2019 :)